# How to catch Spring bean creation error - Injection of autowired dependency?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

AdminService.java

```
    package service;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import dao.IAdminDAO;
    import dao.IMemberDAO;

    public interface AdminService
    {   
        public HashMap<String, Object> adminLogin(String id,String pw);
    }

AdminServiceImple.java
    package service;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import dao.IAdminDAO;

    @Service
    public class AdminServiceImple implements AdminService
    {

        @Autowired
         private IAdminDAO adminDao;

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, Object> adminLogin(String id, String pw) 
        {
            HashMap<String, Object> adminResult = adminDao.selectOne(id);

            if(adminResult != null)
            {
                String opwd = (String) adminResult.get("pw");

                if(opwd.equals(pw))
                {
                    if(adminResult.get("authority").equals(true))
                    {
                        return adminResult;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

AdminController.java

    package controller;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import service.AdminService;
    import service.AdminServiceImple;
    import service.MemberService;

    @Controller
    public class AdminController 
    {
        @Autowired
        public AdminServiceImple adminService;

        // 관리자 로그인 폼 페이지
        @RequestMapping("admin.do")
        public String adminLoginPage()
        {
            return "adminLoginPage";
        }

        // 관리자 로그인했을 시 요청
        @RequestMapping("adminLoginOK.do")
        @ResponseBody
        public String adminMainPage(@RequestParam(required=false) String id, @RequestParam(required=false)String pw,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
        {
            HashMap<String, Object> adminLoginIdentify = adminService.adminLogin(id, pw);

            if(adminLoginIdentify != null)
            {
                return "1";
            }
            else
            {
                return "0";
            }
        }

        @RequestMapping("adminPage.do")
        public String adminPage(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest resquest,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
        {
            return "adminMainPage";
        }
    }
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mybatis-spring="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="dao, service" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="driverClassName"></property>
        <property value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/rachelvf" name="url"></property>
        <property value="root" name="username"/>
        <property value="mysql" name="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:dao/mapper/*.xml"></property>
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="model"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

   <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean"  id="memberDao">
     <property name="mapperInterface" value="dao.IMemberDAO"></property> 
      <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="SqlSessionFactory"></property>
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean"  id="adminDao">
     <property name="mapperInterface" value="dao.IAdminDAO"></property> 
     <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="SqlSessionFactory"></property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

that is error code.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminServiceImple': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.IAdminDAO service.AdminServiceImple.adminDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.IAdminDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
```

I thought about the cause of the error, but I think it is because I did not insert the service annotation.

However, there is no typos in any way, and everything is written correctly and errors occur. Is there something I don't know?

Can you tell me what caused this error?

And what about the solution?

Comment: The IAdminDAO bean is missing... Is the AdminDAO declared as a spring bean?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `AdminDao` bean is creating and injecting correctly into 
`AdminServiceImple`

use this tag in your spring-cfg.xml file

`<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />`

and also scan the controller class using  --

`<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />`

you have to give **information of class which are going to use annotation to IOC container** to create bean...

Comment: I've tried adding the code as you said, but it also throws an error. I can not understand if I speak honestly.

Comment: make sure that you are scanning all classes in which you are going to use annotation except domain class(JavaBean's)

Comment: I added <mybatis-spring: scan base-package = "dao" /> to applicationContext.xml. I also added xmlns: mybatis-spring = "http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring".

Comment: As a result, another error occurred. The error code is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; This is it.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="dao" /> use this tag in place of  <mybatis-spring: scan base-package = "dao" />

Comment: provide your dao class

Comment: `package dao;

import java.util.HashMap;

public interface IAdminDAO 
{
 public HashMap<String, Object> selectOne(String id);
}`  That's all

Comment: implementation of this interface  -- if you don't have implementation class then container initializes with  null values if i'm right then upvote the answer

Comment: So what should I do? Should I implement the DAO interface?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151227/discussion-between-navnath-adsul-and-).

Comment: add this `<context:component-scan base-package="service , dao" />`

Answer (score 0):

A mapper is registered to Spring by including a MapperFactoryBean in your XML config file like follows:

```
<bean id="userMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
      <property name="mapperInterface" value="org.mybatis.spring.sample.mapper.UserMapper" />
      <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to scan your `Service` Package and `Dao` Package.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="dao, service" />
```

above code will scan the `dao` and `service` package respectively.

Comment: Can you have a 1:1 conversation with me?

Comment: i'm sorry, but my chat in stackoverflow here in our office is blocked. what would be your currently issues ?

Comment: I modified the code as you said, but it does not work and I get an error.

Comment: And I modified the applicationContext.xml, but please refer to the above code again.

Comment: The project is still not running. The same error still occurs. I am sad that I can not proceed with the project because of this error.

Comment: put the `IAdminDAO` interface and `IAdminDAOImpl` class. you should put @Repository on top of IAdminDAOImpl, and when you autowire it, you should use `AdminService adminService` and `IAdminDAO adminDAO`.

Comment: I modified the applicationContext file.

Comment: <bean id="adminDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="dao.IAdminDAO"></property>
    </bean>

Comment: <bean id="memberDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="dao.IMemberDAO"></property>
    </bean>

Comment: And I wrote a Sting in the adminDaoMapper. The project is done well by modifying these.